# How to read int and strings from a text file?

Tags: c++, csv

I have a text file containing name, ability, attack, and defense on every line, for instance:

```
Bill Punch 10 5
Jack Jab 7 7
Joe Kick 8 4
```

I would like to read the file and store its content. I could use an array, but I want to be able to continue to add rows. So I've implemented a function to count the lines. Arrays like to complain about values not being static at runtime so I moved to trying a vector. Below is the code.

I'm attempting to insert every value into the x,y of the matrix, then go through and print it. But it's not working; it opens the command prompt and asks to input my file name. I do that, but then it just stops running.

Also, how can I return the vector to my `main` function?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// Global Variables
int numLines = 0;
string fileName;
int countLines();
string openFile();

int main() {
    string name, attack;
    cout << "What is the name of your data file?" << endl;
    getline(cin, fileName);
    cout << countLines() << endl;
    cout << openFile() << endl;
}
int countLines() {
    ifstream dataFile(fileName);
    string line;
    while (getline(dataFile, line)) {
        numLines++;
    }
    return numLines;
}
string openFile() {
    vector<vector<int>> dataVec(numLines, vector<int>(4));
    ifstream dataFile(fileName);
    string line;
    while (getline(dataFile, line)) {
        for (int i = 0; i == numLines - 1; i++) {
            for (int o = 0; o == 4; o++) {
                cin >> dataVec[i][o];
            }
        }
    }
    while (getline(dataFile, line)) {
        for (int i = 0; i == numLines - 1; i++) {
            for (int o = 0; o == 4; o++) {
                cout << dataVec[i][o];
            }
        }
    }
    return dataVec;
}
```

Comment: What do you think should happen when your loop condition is `for (int i = 0; i == numLines - 1; i++)`?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Functions outside of `main` can't use or see the `firstName` and `lastName` variables.

Comment: The variable `dataVec` is local to the function `openFile` and will disappear when execution leaves the function.  You may want to consider making it a global variable, passing it by reference or using a class for all this stuff.

Comment: You will need to reposition the file pointer to the beginning before calling `openFile`.  The function `countLines` will set the file position to the end and set an error condition.  So, you will need to clear the error condition and reset the file position to to the beginning.

Comment: Is using `cin` in your `openFile` a typo?  You get a line of data from the file, then get data from the User (without a prompt).  Is this intentional?  This is not common practices when using CSV files (usually everything is read from the one file).

Answer (score 1):

There are better methods to read a CSV than you are using.  Your method to read in a file of data are complicated and injecting defects.  Simplifying your algorithm can reduce the number of defects.

For example, using a structure to model the data row.  Let us call each line of data, a record.

```
struct Record
{
  std::string first_name;
  std::string last_name;
  int         number1;
  int         number2;
};
```

You can store the records into a simple `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
```

One method is to have the `Record` read in its data members:

```
    struct Record
    {
      std::string first_name;
      std::string last_name;
      int         number1;
      int         number2;
      friend istream& operator>>(istream& input, Record& r);
    };

istream& operator>>(istream& input, Record& r)
{
  input >> r.first_name;
  input >> r.last_name;
  input >> r.number1;
  input >> r.number2;
  return input;
};
```

This enables you to simplify your input loop:

```
Record r;
while (data_file >> r)
{
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

If you need to know the number of lines in the file, you could use `database.size()`.  Otherwise, there is no need to know the number of lines in the file.

Similarly, you can write methods to print the record.  If you overload `operator<<`, your print statement becomes:

```
cout << database[i] << endl;
```

Comment: I am using a text file not a csv file.

Comment: @user1686765 Logic is the same. Only the delimiter would change. As it is though, I think Thomas Matthews merely mis-wrote. There is no comma parsing in this code.

Comment: The CSV format represents fields in a text file that are *delimiter* separated, whether it be comma, space, semicolon or tab.